# How to check if a substring exists inside a 'Result' object with Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am running the following test inside Robot Framework:

```
   *** Settings ***
   Documentation           This initializes testrun.robot
   Library                 Process
   Library                 OperatingSystem
   Library                 XML
   Library                 Collections

   Output Is A Valid XML File Against JATS format
       Start Process         xmllint --dtdvalid http://jats.nlm.nih.gov/archiving/1.1d3/JATS-archivearticle1.dtd ./output/nlm/out.xml        shell=True
       ${result}=            Wait For Process      timeout=45 secs
       Log                   ${result.stdout}
       Log                   ${result.stderr}
       Run Keyword Unless      '${result.stderr} == ${EMPTY}'     Should Contain      ${result.stderr}  element xref: validity error : IDREFS attribute rid references an unknown
```

The variable ${result.stderr} is a string that contains the substring 'element xref: validity error : IDREFS attribute rid references an unknown'. As far as I know, I'm not dealing with any whitespace errors or quotation problems, although I could be wrong. (I've been fiddling around with that for a while now.)

Thanks for the help!

Edit: The log that Robot Framework generates tells me that the process has finished (that's how I know what result.stderr contains.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this statement:

```
Run Keyword Unless      '${result.stderr} == ${EMPTY}'    ...
```

The keyword will never run because you aren't comparing two variables, you are simply checking whether the string literal string `'${result.stderr} == ${EMPTY}'` is not empty (and it's not, because it has 28 characters).

It is the same as if you did this in python:

```
if len('${result.stderr} == ${EMPTY}') > 0:
    ...
```

You need to put the single quotes around each variable separately so that you are  passing a valid expression to the if statement, rather than a string that *looks* like a valid expression:

```
Run Keyword Unless      '${result.stderr}' == '${EMPTY}'    ...
```

Comment: Would quotes need to be put around every variable in the conditional statement? Should quotes be put around the string literal? What should I do in the event that there are quotes inside the string literal?

Comment: @JosephNicolls: after robot replaces the variables with their values, the result needs to be valid python code. From the documentation: _"If condition is a string (e.g. ${rc} < 10), it is evaluated as a Python expression using the built-in eval function and the keyword status is decided based on the result. If a non-string item is given, the status is got directly from its truth value."_

Comment: @JosephNicolls: note that if  your variable has single quotes you may need to use double quotes. If your variable is a number that you're comparing to another number, you don't need the quotes.

Comment: That doesn't appear to fix my issue. My concern for what came after the conditional statement, the part of the code that reads: Should Contain      ${result.stderr}  element xref: validity error : IDREFS attribute rid references an unknown. Should any part of that be quoted?

Comment: @JosephNicolls: no, you don't need quotes with `Should Contain` -- quotes are only required for the "if" keywords (`Run keyword if`, `Run keyword unless`, etc). And strictly speaking, quotes aren't required. What _is_ required is that the value after substitution is a valid python expression. You may need single quotes, you may need double quotes, you may need triple quotes, you may need no quotes at all. It really depends on the nature of the data.